# sharing ByteArray between threads (flash Workers)

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to use a thread on my flex application, the thread needs to use an object that i want to pass using the `worker.setSharedProperty("bytes",bytes)`  , bytes.sharable is set to true,

The serialised object implements IExternalizable with the RemoteClass tag since it is serialised on different other scenarios (cloning, saving to DB etc.) however when sending to the worker thread i am getting this error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2173: Unable to read object in stream.  The class com.model.vo.ProjectVO does not implement flash.utils.IExternalizable but is aliased to an externalizable class.
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/readObject()
```

I did try the following 2 solutions:

1. `registerClassAlias("com.model.vo.ProjectVO",ProjectVO)`  as suggested on this [link](http://codelightyear.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/argumenterror-error-2173-unable-to-read.html)
2. On my thread calling the ProjectVO instance as suggested here: [link](http://flash-secrets.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/argumenterror-error-2173-unable-to-read.html)

Non of this worked, my guess is that it has to do with trying to pass objects that implement IExternalizable and would like to hear if anyone succeeded in that.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice question! Would love to hear some opinions :)